# Are options and WithSize etc in XPlot specific to only certain charts?

Tags: f#, fslab

I've tried `Chart.WithSize` and `displayZoomButtons = true` in the FSLab tutorial, but nothing seems to change the output.

Same thing in other projects using XPlot.GoogleCharts directly.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: can you use XPlot.Plotly instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Plotly 1.4.2 from nuget and replace the dlls in the FSLab packages directory for XPlotly (see [Plotting with Xplotly Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962034/plotting-data-of-deedle-data-frame-with-xplot-plotly)). Then you can use Xplotly's controls to zoom in and out, save the chart, etc. For example:

```
#load @"..\..\FSLAB\packages\FsLab\FsLab.fsx"
open XPlot.Plotly
open XPlot.Plotly.Graph
open XPlot.Plotly.Html
//open XPlot.GoogleCharts

let layout = Layout(title = "Basic Bar Chart")
["giraffes", 20; "orangutans", 14; "monkeys", 23]
    |> Chart.Bar
    |> Chart.WithLayout layout
    |> Chart.WithHeight 400
    |> Chart.WithWidth 700
    |> Chart.Show
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like there are a lot of charts that aren't exposed through `XPlot.Plotly`... notably, candlesticks, pies and calendars are missing :/

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka Yes, I noticed. I'm not very familiar with GoogleCharts in Xplot but I had the same problem, could not resize the chart. You might want to file an issue on github.

Comment: I've decided to try implementing my own html/javascript charting proxy. Shouldn't be too hard with an embedded ASP.Net Core server, and it'll give me access to all the free javascript visualization libraries.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka would be nice to see it on github. :)

Comment: Maybe! It won't be very much code, since I don't intend to make it nearly as composable or configurable as XPlot -- just going to hard-code most of the generated html/js in an .fsx file so I can mess with it directly. It's probably more suited for a blog entry -- except I don't have a blog right now. I'll figure something out.

Comment: Actually, I just realized -- it's not necessary to use a web server for this; just generate an .html file, save it in the temp folder, and `Process.Start()` it. Derp.

Answer (score 0):

Very barebones charting solution using Plotly (and it works):

```
open Newtonsoft.Json

let html = """<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
  <script>
    var data = __DATA__;
    var layout = __LAYOUT__;
    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
  </script>
</body>"""

let (=>) k v = k, (v:>obj)

let doPlot data layout =
    let data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject data
    let layout = JsonConvert.SerializeObject layout
    let path = Path.GetTempPath() + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".html"
    File.WriteAllText(path, html.Replace("__DATA__", data).Replace("__LAYOUT__", layout))
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path)

let layout =
    [ "title" => "Plot"
      "xaxis" => dict [
        "title" => "Ticks"
        "showgrid" => false
        "zeroline" => false
      ]
      "yaxis" => dict [
        "title" => "Price"
        "showline" => false
      ]
    ] |> dict

let data = [
    dict [ "x" => [1999; 2000; 2001; 2002]
           "y" => [16; 5; 11; 9]
         ]
    ]

doPlot data layout
```